# Biztalk 2009 install help

Tags: biztalk

I try to install Biztalk2009, with SQL 2008R2CTPNov, on Win Server 2008. I'm blocked at the configuration step "groups" :

```
[19:22:18 Info Configuration Framework]Configuring feature: WMI
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::ConfigureFeature
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg]  Configuring feature: WMI
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::Connect
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] WMI is already connected
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CWMI::Connect
[19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper]    NT group BizTalk Server Operators was not created because it already exists
[19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] Le groupe local spécifié existe déjà.
[19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper]    NT group BizTalk Server Administrators was not created because it already exists
[19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] Le groupe local spécifié existe déjà.
[19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::CreateGroup
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0527 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() try to acquire lock
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0539 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() lock acquired successfully
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0546 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::VerifyMgmtDbCompatibility(CInstance) started
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0553 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::VerifyMgmtDbCompatibility(CInstance) finished successfully
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0564 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance(MSBTS_GroupSetting.MgmtDbName="BizTalkMgmtDb",MgmtDbServerName="ECTXEVLBZTK") started
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0572 [INFO] WMI CAdapter::ConvertWMI2Admin() started
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0581 [INFO] WMI CDataContainer::SetWCHAR() - Possible problem: item value is overwritten
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0591 [INFO] WMI CAdapter::ConvertWMI2Admin() finished with HR=0
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0611 [INFO] WMI QueryStringValue query regkey 'MgmtDBServer'
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0620 [INFO] WMI CAdmCoreGroupInst::TryCreateNewGroup() started
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0632 [INFO] WMI Creating Mgmt database...
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0641 [INFO] WMI Calling CDataSource.Open() against ECTXEVLBZTK\master
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0792 [INFO] WMI CDataSource.Open() returned
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0810 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=80040e1d; Msg=Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.; 
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0824 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=c0c02524; Msg=Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.; 
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0835 [ERR] WMI Failed in pAdmInst->Create() in CWMIInstProv::PutInstance(). HR=c0c02524
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0846 [ERR] WMI WMI error description is generated: Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.
2010-01-14 19:22:18:0860 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() finished. HR=c0c02524
[19:22:18 Error BtsCfg] f:\bt\890\private\source\setup\prod\btssetup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(358): FAILED hr = c0c02524

[19:22:18 Error BtsCfg] Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.
```

It seems that the install can't create Managment database, But the SSO database is created OK...

Has someone a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Uninstall Biztalk Server 2009, uninstall SQL Server 2008 R2. 
2) Install SQL Server 2008.
3) Reinstall Biztalk Server 2009.
4) Configure Biztalk Server 2009.

SQL Server 2008 R2 is not supported by Biztalk Server 2009.